# Content-Type in for individual files in python requests

Tags: python, request, content-type

I want to request to my server running in python flask with file and some meta information. Hence my request content-Type will be 'multipart/form-data. Is there a way i can set the content type of file like image/jpg, image/gif etc...
How do i set the content-type for the file. Is it possible or not

Comment: Have you tried something? This sounds like something that would be explained in documentation.

Comment: @SimeonVisser: Although this is possible, it is *not* documented anywhere, actually.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: fair enough, looks like you've answered the question below.

Comment: The document is here http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/#post-multiple-multipart-encoded-files

Answer (score 36, accepted):

If you make each file specification a tuple, you can specify the mime type as a third parameter:

```
files = {
    'file1': ('foo.gif', open('foo.gif', 'rb'), 'image/gif'),
    'file2': ('bar.png', open('bar.png', 'rb'), 'image/png'),
}
response = requests.post(url, files=files)
```

You can give a 4th parameter as well, which must be a dictionary with additional headers for each part.

See the [Requests API documentation](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/#requests.request):

> `file-tuple` can be a 2-tuple `('filename', fileobj)`, 3-tuple `('filename', fileobj, 'content_type')` or a 4-tuple `('filename', fileobj, 'content_type', custom_headers)`, where `'content-type'` is a string defining the content type of the given file and `custom_headers` a dict-like object containing additional headers to add for the file.

Answer (score 3):

[reference](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/advanced/#post-multiple-multipart-encoded-files)

```
    import requests

    url = "http://png_upload_example/upload"
    # files = [(<key>, (<filename>, open(<file location>, 'rb'), <content type>))]
    files = [('upload', ('thumbnail.png', open('thumbnail.png', 'rb'), 'image/png'))]

    response = requests.request("POST", url, files = files)
```